# Tail recursion optimization in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

JavaScript will only optimize into a non-recursive loop a recursive step if it is the last expression in a block (IIUC). Does that mean that the right-hand recursive call will be optimised and the left-hand recursive call will NOT in the following?

```
function fibonacci(n) {
  if(n < 2) return n;
  return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}
```

Comment: Define "optimise".

Comment: Transformed into a loop rather than leveraging the call stack.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Meaning the call will use constant stack space only.

Comment: Fair enough. I honestly don't know, but I just wanted to clarify because "optimise" is such a generic term. For instance, you could easily optimise by realising that `fibonacci(n-1)` is almost always going to call `fibonacci(n-2)` as part of its own recursion, so you could optimise that. Or you could have a `known_fib` list that is checked first, and only if a number is not in the list does `fibonacci()` calculate it. (the latter will reduce `fibonacci(n-2)` to a single lookup)

Comment: I dont think so. The upper code cant be written in a loop without taking another approach ( which the parser cant do)

Comment: As both terms are recursive, I don't think it can be optimised into a non-recursive loop.  This can only happen if all terms an be resolved non-recursively except for one.  Whether that one has to be on the right hand side or not will depend on the optimiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does that mean that the right-hand recursive call will be optimised and the left-hand recursive call will NOT in the following?

I don't think so. TCO is only possible when you directly return what other function returns. Since your function processes both results before returning them, neither of the calls can be tail-optimized.

#### Low-level explanation

In terms of a stack-based machine, a code like this:

```
function fun1()
   return fun2(42)

function fun2(arg)
    return arg + 1
```

is translated to this

```
fun1:
    push 42
    call fun2
    result = pop
    push result
    exit

fun2:
    arg = pop
    arg = arg + 1
    push arg
    exit
```

TCO can eliminate call-pop-push and instead jump to `fun2` directly:

```
fun1:
    push 42
    goto fun2
    exit
```

However, a snippet like yours would be this:

```
fun1:
    push n - 1
    call fun2
    result1 = pop

    push n - 2
    call fun2
    result2 = pop

    result3 = result1 + result2
    push result3
    exit
```

Here, it's not possible to replace calls with jumps, because we need to return back to fun1 to perform the addition.

> Disclaimer: this is a rather theoretical explanation, I have no idea how modern JS compilers actually implement TCO. They are quite smart, so perhaps there's a way to optimize stuff like this as well.

Comment: Is the meaning of your first bit of "translated" code for `fun1`: "create a stack frame for the call to `fun2` with `42` as an argument, capture the result in the calling stack frame as the return value for the frame and pop the frame"? Any exposition on why the jump optimisation is valid would be very helpful too.

Comment: *TCO is only possible when you directly return what other function returns.* This is just wrong. For instance, `return 1 + myself();` would be "optimized" just fine.

Comment: @torazaburo: could you elaborate? maybe edit my answer or post a new one?